# Install Ubuntu from Ubuntu install CD partition from OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, partitioning

Is it possible to install Ubuntu by booting from a partition with the Ubuntu install CD image copied to it?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No, i only have acces to my own macbook right now and will need to repartition my disk, wich means i have to delete all my files.

Comment: @user1043056: OS X can resize HFS partitions without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ubuntu with [unetbootin](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-1004-with-usb.html) on your hard disk, boot and than run ubuntu installation. But you will need two partitions. Good way to install ubuntu is from usb stick, that can be done with unetbootin too.